# Display image from database (MySQL via hibernate) in JEditorPane?

Tags: java, image, swing, jeditorpane

i have to display image stored in my database, or e.g. created in program memory, in `JEditorPane`. Is there any way to do it? Thanks for reply.

I forgot tell that my JEditorPane is a WYSIWYG html editor. Html editor mean that, i can edit text like in OpenOffice, but this is still desctop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the image is stored in a BLOB, get an input stream from the blob and pass it to

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(InputStream is);
```

Then have your pane's

```
paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

do among other things

```
g.drawImage(image, transform, observer);
```

Comment: Yea, thanks for reply, but i forgot tell that my JEditorPane is a WYSIWYG html editor.

Comment: well, then if this application is a web application, set up a url to download the image and use the url to show it in the editorpane. If not, you will probably have to write the image to a file, and use a file url to show it.

Comment: This is not a web app, just desctop application.